# Error while deploying to a sandbox using ant

Tags: deployment, ant

I am trying to deploy config data from one sandbox to another sandbox using ant. I am getting 2 errors always.

1. Error: Could not resolve list view column: IDEA.IDEA_THEME (line 78, column 16)
   We dont use Idea object but this always throws an error when i deploy from one sandbox to another.
2. There is always errors with workflows on Question, Reply and socialpost object which we are not using. So we had to delete the objects and workflows manually on the deployment folder and try to deploy to another org.

Do you guys know what would be the solution to these 2 problems?

Comment: Please post your package.xml